# Office: программный подбор синонимов

Tags: c#, python, php, office

Добрый день!

Мучаюсь пару дней пока не подсказали задать вопрос на этом занимательном ресурсе.
Суть вопроса в следующем:
Требуется каким-то образом (сам не понимаю пока каким) взаимодействовать со словарем ms word для подбора синонимов.
Есть текст некоторые слова выделены и выделенные слова нужно подобрать синонимы.А предварительно проверить на ошибки и автоматически изменить.
Как в своем приложении использовать библиотеки, ms word....

Подскажите может есть сторонние библиотеки или что то еще.
Буду благодарен за любую информацию ....

Comment: нет, текст распологается в базе на локальном компьютере, текст вытаскивается из бызы и выделенные слова тегом происходит подбор синонима. Покрайней мере такая задумка

Comment: Тогда пространство имен Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word и MSDN вам в помощь. Что касается словарей, здесь вам не подскажу т.к. с ними не работал.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы работать с офисом нужно работать с пространством имен Microsoft.Office.Interop. При этом, офис должен быть установлен на тот компьютер,  где производится работа с ним. Второе, далее не совсем понятно, где эти слова для подбора у вас размещены, на неком сайте или еще где? Если дело обстоит с сайтом, то тут все сложнее, т.к. вам вряд ли удастся установить на веб сервер офис. Поэтому, в ситуации с сайтом я бы копал в сторону яндекс словарей и искал данную возможность там.